# CUPS - ICC Profile support

Tags: printing, cups, color-profile, color-management

I need to print an image applying an ICC Profile within CUPS. I'm using lp/lpr commands.

Reading the [docs](https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-2.0/spec-ppd.html?VERSION=2.0&Q=), i see that they have the option ***cupsICCProfile**

```
*% Specify a default profile for printing at all other resolutions and media types
*cupsICCProfile ../Default: "/Library/Printers/vendor/Profiles/foo-default.icc"
```

The original PPD file for this printer doesn't have this specific parameter and nothing similar. I tried to add this manually with the correct path but no success.

I also tried some command-line parameters but no success either.

```
$ lp -o profile=1000,1000,1000,0,0,-100,1000,0,0,0,1000
$ lp -o cupsICCProfile=filename.icc filename.jpg
```

Maybe i could try to apply an ICCProfile to the JPG and then print it, but i don't think if it's going to have the same result.

Any suggestions?